# I encountered an error INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE while trying to install APK. adb logcat Output INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK

Tags: android, apk, adb

[About](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNma7.jpg)

Device: Car PC By Android

Version: Android 4.4.2

Use adb install output error code INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE.

But there is more than 80% remaining storage space,Total 1G,Free 900M,So baffled.

I have tried running the below commands from some forum and it is not working for me,

```
    1.adb shell pm set-install-location 2
    2.adb shell pm uninstall com.package.app   
      adb shell rm -rf /data/app/com.package.name-*
    3.adb shell rm -rf /data/local/tmp/*
    4.adb shell rm -rf /data/klog/*
    5.Restore factory settings
```

Last analyzing the log without identifying the cause,I hope to receive everyone's help.

Thanks!

adb logcat Output Details:

```
    05-07 09:08:06.737 E/MCU_SERVER(  856): </dev/ttyMT4 Recv 16 bytes>: 02 81 D1 0B 0A 38 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 69
    05-07 09:08:06.738 E/MCU_SERVER(  856): <dispatched data>: 02 81 D1 0B 0A 38 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 69
    05-07 09:08:06.738 E/mcu_services(  358): processResponse - mCmdCode: 0xD1 - mCmdLength: 12
    
    05-07 09:08:06.744 I/installd(   83): install, pkgname(com.estrongs.android.pop), uid: 10025, gid: 10025
    05-07 09:08:06.744 I/installd(   83): install, pkgname(com.estrongs.android.pop), pkgdir: (/data/data/com.estrongs.android.pop)
    05-07 09:08:06.745 I/installd(   83): install, pkgname(com.estrongs.android.pop), libsymlink(/data/data/com.estrongs.android.pop/lib), applibdir: (/data/app-lib/com.estrongs.android.pop)
    05-07 09:08:06.745 W/PackageManager(  358): createDataDirsLI:com.estrongs.android.pop
    05-07 09:08:06.745 W/PackageManager(  358): createDataDirsLI ckx INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK!!!
    05-07 09:08:06.745 W/PackageManager(  358): Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.estrongs.android.pop-1.apk**
    
    05-07 09:08:06.820 E/MCU_SERVER(  856): </dev/ttyMT4 Recv 49 bytes>: 02 81 D1 10 0A 40 00 00 00 01 00 00 1F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 14 02 81 D1 17 0A 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 78
    05-07 09:08:06.820 E/MCU_SERVER(  856): <dispatched data>: 02 81 D1 10 0A 40 00 00 00 01 00 00 1F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 14
    05-07 09:08:06.820 E/MCU_SERVER(  856): <dispatched data>: 02 81 D1 17 0A 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 78
    05-07 09:08:06.838 E/mcu_services(  358): processResponse - mCmdCode: 0xD1 - mCmdLength: 17
    05-07 09:08:06.847 D/AirCondition(  666): AirCondition{airType=1, isAirWorking=false, temp_A=22, temp_E=1, speed=0, cycleMode=OUT, blowMode=FACE, frontDefrost=false, backDefrost=false}
    05-07 09:08:06.852 D/dalvikvm(  358): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1576K, 21% free 8888K/11184K, paused 5ms+38ms, total 106ms
    05-07 09:08:06.857 E/mcu_services(  358): processResponse - mCmdCode: 0xD1 - mCmdLength: 24
    05-07 09:08:06.876 I/WindowState(  358):  WindowState -- LayoutParams a=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(wrapxwrap) gr=#11 sim=#120 ty=2 fl=#1820002 pfl=0x8 fmt=-2 wanim=0x1030296}
    05-07 09:08:07.017 E/MCU_SERVER(  856): </dev/ttyMT4 Recv 39 bytes>: 02 81 D1 15 0A 37 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 78 02 81 D1 08 0A 33 00 00 00 00 00 00 61
    05-07 09:08:07.017 E/MCU_SERVER(  856): <dispatched data>: 02 81 D1 15 0A 37 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 78
    05-07 09:08:07.018 E/MCU_SERVER(  856): <dispatched data>: 02 81 D1 08 0A 33 00 00 00 00 00 00 61
    05-07 09:08:07.018 E/mcu_services(  358): processResponse - mCmdCode: 0xD1 - mCmdLength: 22
    05-07 09:08:07.023 D/NotificationService(  430): ===other event : 32 .package:com.android.packageinstaller .text:
    05-07 09:08:07.035 E/mcu_services(  358): processResponse - mCmdCode: 0xD1 - mCmdLength: 9
```

Comment: Some of your posted commands using `rm` only work on a rooted device with adb in root mode. Are you aware that "ES File Explorer" app was removed from Play Store because of "security problem"/ malicious activities? If on your car Android system Google Play Protection is active this could be reason for the INVALID_APK message.

Comment: The rm command was successfully executed, and the file has been verified to be deleted correctly. Besides the "ES File Explorer", it's also the same mistake.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.